# How to create view with user's flagged content?

Tags: 7, views, flags

I created a flag 'Add to favorites' with the [Flag](https://drupal.org/project/flag) module and I'd now like to create a view for the user's profile that sums up all his/her favorite content. I tried to add the relationship **Flags: add_to_favorites (by current user)** to my view, but then the favorites of the logged in user appear on every profile page.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a contextual filter "Flag: User ID", and provide a default value, "Get UID from URL". Also I think you need too change the relationship to Flags: add_to_favorites (any user)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding contextual filters -> USER -> get uid from url