# View with terms and if the're flagged or not on userpage

Tags: views, flags

I want to make a subscription-page on the users-page. A user can flag terms. On the user-page there should

1) It's *no problem* to get a view with flagged content

- relationship Flags [flag name]
- contextual filter Flags: User uid

(see [How to create view with user's flagged content?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88460/how-to-create-view-with-users-flagged-content)). The view shows only flagged terms.

2) It's *no problem* to get a view with flagged and not-flagged content

- relationship Flags [flag name] with current user & include only flagged content NOT checked
- path like /subscription

But as soon when i alter the path to user/%/subscribtion, every user can see other subscriptions by altering the path. When using this path with option 1), i see only flagged content (??). Removing the contextual filter, shows all content but accesible for everyone.

*How can i restrict the access to the own subscriptions, showing flagged and unflagged terms?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views only has 2 means to restrict access to Views: via a role or via a permission. Neither can help here so you'll have to use some other means to restrict the route path.

One way to go about this is to use the [Views Access Callback module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_access_callback) which was built for the purpose of dynamically checking access to a View. Once enabled, any module can implement `hook_views_access_callbacks()` to define a custom callback that can be used for permission checks.

It should be pretty easy to define a simple callback that inspects the current path to see if it belongs to the current user:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_access_callbacks().
 */
function MYMODULE_views_access_callbacks() {
  return array(
    'MYMODULE_access_account_subpages' => t('Access Account Subpages'),
  );
}

/**
 * Check that the user is the owner of the subpage.
 */
function MYMODULE_access_account_subpages($account = NULL) {
  global $user;
  return (arg(0) == 'user' && $user->uid == arg(1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this comment was helpfull. Didn't know that there (by default) only 2 ways to restrict access. Because of the simplicity of the site (KISS) we use option 2 - in this way it's more clear for future admins.